# Excel Count on Row and Column, multiple criteria

Tags: excel

whats the best way forward to count multipul criteria on two axis?

```
    A        B     C       D      E 
1 Project  Rating  Jan 1  Jan 2  Jan 3
2 Pro A      A      0       7      0
3 Pro B      A      0       0      0
4 Pro C      B      0       1      0
5 Pro D      C      5       5      5
6 Pro E      A      7       0      7
```

If you can imagine this extends for the entire year

I want to know How many Projects Rated A have hours logged agasint them for each month. The answer above would be 2.

Comment: Is this for a past year where you have data for the **entire** year......or do you want it to work in an ongoing manner, e.g. for this year you will only currently have January data?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

- Add a column of cells (let's call it `HasHours`) that sum up all of the data cells (columns C and rightward in your example) in their row, and then uses `IF` to return 1 if the sum is greater than 0 and 0 otherwise.
- Add a summary table at the bottom or top with columns `Rating` and `# Projects`. In the `Rating` column, put all possible ratings ("A," "B," and "C"?). In the `# Projects` column, put a formula that applies `[SUMIF][1]` with the range being the Rating column in the main data table, the criteria being the cell in the Rating column of the summary table on each row, and the sum range being the `HasHours` column you created in the main data table. This will add up all of those 1s and 0s to give you the number of projects with any hours for each rating.